# How to provide Deep link to Metamask browser only from mobile phone browsers?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, metamask

I have a web app in react that is connecting to Metamask from the chrome browser. As there is no Metamask extension for the chrome app on android or ios devices you have to open your web app inside the Metamask app in order to connect to the Metamsk.
I want to detect whether my website is running on a mobile device or tablet so that I can prompt the user to click on the Metamask deep-link to open the website in the Metamask app.